# Why am i getting a white screen after I enabled debugging?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I have been working on a plugin, and when I refreshed the admin page its white. I have enabled all the debugging options on the wp-config file and its still showing a white screen. I have deleted all the code on the plugin I was working on which I assumed caused the white screen and still nothing happens.

Does anyone know how I else I can debug this issue?

Below is my wp-config file. I don't know if I am missing anything or not.

```
**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE);



// Tells WordPress to log everything to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Doesn't force the PHP 'display_errors' variable to be on
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', TRUE);

// Hides errors from being displayed on-screen
//@ini_set('display_errors', 0);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: Can you login to admin ? if so - try to reactivate your theme . also, what happens if you disable debugging ? and what does your log say ? I would also change `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to `@ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: No I can't even login to admin, i tried setting @ini_set('display_errors', 1); doesn't work

Comment: that would mean you have some bug , or syntax error /

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue...

I didn't wrap ABSPATH using a string..

```
if(!defined(ABSPATH)){

    exit;
}
```

i changed it to

```
if(!defined("ABSPATH")){

    exit;
}
```

Comment: well, in your pasted code in Original question, there are single quotes .. `if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');`